# DynamoDB: Is it possible to add and delete from the same list attribute in one update request?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have DynamoDB items in which I want to store a "round robin" kind of list, so that I can add new items, but I never want the list to be longer than N elements.

I figured I could do this using:

```
SET items = list_append(["new_value"], items) 
DELETE items[3]
```

I thought this should work, since DELETE:ing an attribute that doesn't exist should be a no-op according to the documentation, so if the list has 0-2 elements after the new element is added first in the list, I would not delete anything; otherwise I would delete the 4th element, always keeping the list at a maximum size of 3 (assuming no other updates add elements without housekeeping).

However, DynamoDB fails with this message:

```
Invalid UpdateExpression: Two document paths overlap with each other; 
  must remove or rewrite one of these paths; 
path one: [items], path two: [items, [3]]
```

Quite frustrating that updating an array element and modifying the array itself using `list_append` is considered two overlapping operations.

Is there a way to to do what I want in a single request?
The closest thing I've got is to manually shift every element in the list, and it works if the max size is small, but also feels *very* ugly (here shown for max=3):

```
SET items[2] = if_not_exists(items[1], null)
    items[1] = if_not_exists(items[0], null)
    items[0] = "new_value"
```

I know that I can solve this using multiple requests, but it comes at a small cost and performance increase of course, but above all I found the challenge interesting. :)

Comment: Hey @JHH, did you end up finding any resolution for this?

Comment: Hi @KarthikRP, no I did not. I had to abandon my ingenious plan and go for a more traditional get-modify-update cycle (which means wasting capacity units but also having to handle concurrent updates). Too bad! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to accomplish this with a single request. The standard technique is to get the item, update it client-side, and write it again using optimistic concurrency control to ensure nobody else modified the item while you were working with it.